# Issues with instace mode and using cloudflare, p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, multiple-instances

I am currently trying to use instancing mode to show multiple p5 sketches on a web page. I have created my instance like this: `let sketch = function(o)`.

The error that occurs says: "o.setup() is not a function", and then references the call to cloudflare. However I can't see why it doesn't like o.setup(). I have called `let grid = new p5(sketch)` and the end of the document.

Any thoughts or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html. It does sound like you understand what you're saying. Do you have a small example maybe? on jsfiddle or editor.p5js.org. That always helps to find the problem quicker.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using Dan Shiffman's video which seems to cover the same information. The website is live [here](https://callumfowler101.github.io/interaction.html). And is hosted on [this git repo](https://github.com/callumfowler101/callumfowler101.github.io). Feel free to have a look, I am quite stumped atm... could it be to do with me using cloudflare to reference p5? I am quite new to web dev and using external libraries like this.

Comment: `o.setup() = () => {` this doesn't seem right.  It should work with `o.setup = () => {` The () after o.setup are saying you want to execute o.setup, instead of defining it. 
It's supposed to be a carousel of p5 sketches? I'm thinking instancing isn't the best solution there, i believe it will run every instance at the same time, won't that be super slow? Maybe you can find another way of changing them dynamically?

Comment: Thanks Ethan for your spot! Managed to get it working after removing those extra brackets on the functions. The carousel CSS is for another page on the website, but the plan is to have a couple more sketches on the webpage so may need to look at making it more efficent. Managed to get it working although there are still a few bugs needing to be ironed out! Thanks again though :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Did you see how quickly we fixed it, when some code was shared? :p It's always recommended to add a minimal code example with questions on SO, provides a lot more context. For next time :)